# MongoDB query inside a subdocument

Tags: pymongo

I have the following Mongo collection:

```
[
{_id: 0,
'doc1': {'name': 'Albert', 'age': 40}},
{_id: 1,
'doc2': {'name': 'Benjamin', 'age': 13}},
{_id: 2,
'doc3': {'name': 'Charlie', 'age': 13}},
...
]
```

I would like to write a query that filters for age or any other field inside these subdocuments.

Answer (score 1):

Use dot notation to search inside objects:

```
db.collection.find({'name.age': 13})
```